# Adding security identities to allow remote desktop access to EC2 instance once created

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2

How can you add security identities to an EC2 instance to allow
remote desktop access using Powershell?

The EC2 instance is already created and joined the Domain. Now i Want to add some other security identities to allow remote desktop access.

Comment: If you have something to add to your question please edit your question and not write it as comment. Otherwise, can you add some context? What is your code and what did you try? Are EC2 instances the Amazon EC2 Instance Types?

Comment: Did you read this documentation? [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-ec2-launch.html) ? `New-EC2SecurityGroup -GroupName myPSSecurityGroup -GroupDescription "EC2-Classic from PowerShell"` This is an example.

Comment: Yes Alex_P, I have already read that but that is a different scenario.